# How to do skip and limit process in angular 2?

Tags: json, angular, scroll

I will get JSON data in my project. I have to show that data in table. Here I have to show first 6 items only for first time. Then user scrolls down then I have to append another 6 items. How to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [angular2-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll).

Mostly we want to scroll, because of huge data size coming from Backend so we want to call fix no of rows using API then again we call API for next rows either on click a button or using a scroll.

Hope this will help you Or you can create your own scrolling module.

Check out:

```
Plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/DrEDetYnZkFxR7OWWrxS?p=preview
```

given by angular2-infinite-scroll.

Comment: Thanks.. actually I want to display in multiple pages...if possible create another plunker for pagination..Thanks in advance